# error: Failed to execute goal

Tags: maven, path, android-studio, pom.xml

I have downloaded Robolectric sample code from [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric), and I am testing it over Android studio. I followed steps mentioned [in this link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57193). 
the path has to be mentioned in the pom.xml file. I am not sure what it is exactly. This is my pom.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>5</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
<artifactId>robolectricsample</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>RobolectricSample app</name>
<description>Sample project demonstrating use of the Robolectric Android testing project.</description>
<url>https://github.com/pivotal/RobolectricSample</url>

<properties>
    <robolectric.version>2.0</robolectric.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
        <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <classifier>no_aop</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>${robolectric.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6)-->
                    <platform>17</platform>


                </sdk>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/Test*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<scm>
    <url>git@github.com:pivotal/RobolectricSample.git</url>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/pivotal/RobolectricSample.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:pivotal/RobolectricSample.git</developerConnection>
</scm>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>tyler</id>
        <name>Tyler Schultz</name>
        <email>tyler@pivotallabs.com</email>
        <organization>Pivotal Labs</organization>
        <organizationUrl>http://pivotallabs.com/</organizationUrl>
        <roles>
            <role>Project Owner</role>
            <role>Developer</role>
        </roles>
        <timezone>PST/PDT</timezone>
    </developer>
    <developer>
        <id>phil</id>
        <name>Phil Goodwin</name>
        <email>phil@pivotallabs.com</email>
        <organization>Pivotal Labs</organization>
        <organizationUrl>http://pivotallabs.com/</organizationUrl>
        <roles>
            <role>Developer</role>
        </roles>
        <timezone>PST/PDT</timezone>
    </developer>
    <developer>
        <id>joemoore</id>
        <name>Joe Moore</name>
        <email>joe@pivotallabs.com</email>
        <organization>Pivotal Labs</organization>
        <organizationUrl>http://pivotallabs.com/</organizationUrl>
        <roles>
            <role>Developer</role>
        </roles>
        <timezone>EST/EDT</timezone>
    </developer>
</developers>
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>MIT license</name>
        <comments>
            The MIT License

            Copyright (c) 2011 Pivotal Labs

            Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
            of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
            in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
            to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
            copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
            furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

            The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
            all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

            THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
            IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
            FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
            AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
            LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
            OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
            THE SOFTWARE.
        </comments>
    </license>
</licenses>
```

the error i am getting is as follows:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\apache-maven-3.0.5" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\m2.conf" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Users\ashish\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\apache-maven-3.0.5\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;C:\Users\ashish\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher test

Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project robolectricsample: No Android SDK path could be found. You may configure it in the plugin configuration section in the pom file using ... or ... or on command-line using -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or by setting environment variable ANDROID_HOME -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1

Please help me out, Thanx in advance

Comment: I don't see any error in what you have listed as the error, only what command and parameters you are running.

Comment: @DanielBarbarian Please look at the errors now. I have edited the post. Thanks for letting me know